# Play WebSockets don't work on Apache Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, playframework, websocket

I was trying to use WebSockets in my Play project, but seems, that play2war package I am using  does not support websocket handling. Now I wonder, whether there is any alternative way to deploy play project on tomcat or maybe some good substitute to websockets?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it vital that you use Tomcat?

Comment: I suppose so, actually, my aim is being able to deploy the project to wide spread servers, and for sure Tomcat is one of those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems as though there is no support for WebSockets (yet). https://github.com/dlecan/play2-war-plugin
You could try and implement [socket.io](http://socket.io/) which has an active Java implementation [here](https://github.com/mrniko/netty-socketio). Socket.io supports a variety of mechanisms for realtime communication in your browser.